# How to use ObjectId on client side given string _id?

Tags: typescript, mongodb, next.js, next.js13

How do I get a document given the `_id` in string?

The code in the client side looks as such:

```
'use client'

...

const Page(){

      ...

      fetch("api/get_data", {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                query: {
                    "$match": { "_id": str_id }
                },
                limit: 1
            })
        })
}
```

and my next.js13 backend api which actually fetches the data `/api/get_data/route.ts`:

```
export async function POST(request: Request) {

    ...

    await DATA_COLLECTION?.aggregate([
                body.query
            ])?.limit(body.limit)?.toArray()

}
```

I **would** have used `ObjectId` like this:

```
"$match": {
    "_id": new ObjectId(str_id)
}
```

but it gives the error:

> ```
> Module not found: Can't resolve 'child_process'
>
> https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found
>
> Import trace for requested module:
> ./node_modules/mongodb/lib/client-side-encryption/auto_encrypter.js
> ./node_modules/mongodb/lib/index.js
> ```

[image]

Comment: Given you're `JSON.stringify`ing it, what do you think the difference between `str_id` and `new ObjectId(str_id)` is?

Comment: @jonrsharpe ah it seems to be converted into a string, I'm guessing in the api route I'll have to convert that string to `ObjectId` and then pass it to the `aggregate()`? But is there any way to directly query in aggregate with a string ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution [here](https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/aggregate-match-id-eq-toobjectid-not-working/145965/4)

```
{ $match: { $expr : { $eq: [ '$_id' , { $toObjectId: str_id } ] } } }
```

writing it in fetch as:

```
fetch("api/get_data", {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                query: { $match: { $expr : { $eq: [ '$_id' , { $toObjectId: str_id } ] } } }},
                limit: 1
            })
        })
```